# Query a search widget using jsoup

Tags: java, web-crawler, jsoup

I want to query the below site and get all the result in to a csv file:

> http://services2.hdb.gov.sg/webapp/BB33RTIS/BB33SSearchWidget

I already have a program for this(which was written by the previous programmer and I am trying to understand the code as I am a beginner in jsoup and web crawling) , but now the site is updated and the query no longer works. I think I need to update the URL. Below is the url string I am currently using:

```
private final static String URL = "http://services2.hdb.gov.sg/webapp/BB33RTIS/BB33SSearchWidget?"
        + "client=default"
        + "&proxystylesheet=default"
        + "&output=xml_no_dtd"
        + "&Process=continue"
        + "&FLAT_TYPE=%s"
        + "&NME_NEWTOWN=%s"
        + "&NME_STREET="
        + "&NUM_BLK_FROM="
        + "&NUM_BLK_TO="
        + "&AMT_RESALE_PRICE_FROM="
        + "&AMT_RESALE_PRICE_TO="
        + "&DTE_APPROVAL_FROM=%s"
        + "&DTE_APPROVAL_TO=%s";
```

And the I connect like this:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
```

I want to update it to use the new URL. I checked in the page source, but could not find it. Can anybody please help me to find the URL f the that I need to pass here.

Comment: Do you know what the current url is? Are you asking how to implement an update of the document or how to change this url?

Comment: I have included the current URL. I am asking how to change the URL. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To figure out the way a site works you can open *Firebug* or *Chrome Developer Tools* and inspect the network traffic. There you can inspect what is sent over the wire (data, *GET* or *POST*, cookies, ...).

For this site you will need to post the data, but you will also need to have a couple of cookies set, else the site won't accept your *POST* request. You can do this by simply sending a *GET* request first and read the cookies:

```
Response res = Jsoup
    .connect("http://services2.hdb.gov.sg/webapp/BB33RTIS/BB33SSearchWidget")
    .timeout(10000) // edit: set timeout to 10 seconds
    .method(GET)
    .execute();

Map<String,String> cookies = res.cookies();
```

Now you can send your *POST* request using the `cookies`:

```
Document doc = Jsoup
   .connect("http://services2.hdb.gov.sg/webapp/BB33RTIS/BB33SSearchWidget")
   .timeout(10000) // edit: set timeout to 10 seconds
   .data("FLAT_TYPE", "02")
   .data("NME_NEWTOWN", "BD      Bedok")
   .data("NME_STREET", "")
   .data("NUM_BLK_FROM", "")
   .data("NUM_BLK_TO", "")
   .data("dteRange", "12")
   .data("DTE_APPROVAL_FROM", "Apr 2015")
   .data("DTE_APPROVAL_TO", "Apr 2016")
   .data("AMT_RESALE_PRICE_FROM", "")
   .data("AMT_RESALE_PRICE_TO", "")
   .data("Process", "continue")
   .cookies(cookies)
   .post();
```

And use `doc` to scrape the search results.

Note: sending a *GET* request with the *URL-encoded* data didn't work for me

Comment: Thanks @nyname00. I tried your code, but then I got an error as "package Connection does not exist". I have added "importorg.jsoup.Connection.Response; 
import org.jsoup.Connection.Method;" And I updated my jsoup version from 1.7.2 to 1.9.1 as well.

Comment: @gishara strange, you shouldn't get a `package xyz does not exist` from a wrong import, rather a `import xyz cannot be resolved`. How do you compile your program?
Btw, I'm using `import static org.jsoup.Connection.Method.GET;`and
`import org.jsoup.Connection.Response;` on 1.9.1

Comment: thanks @nyname00. I am using maven to compile the program.

Comment: @gishara maven compilation works for me. without more info it's hard to tell, but this looks like your classpath is somehow incorrect. Can you compile/run the code directly from within your IDE?

Comment: Thanks for the reply nyname00. I could not compile the program within my IDE (eclipse). :(

Comment: @gishara same error? can you check whether jsoup is on your classpath

Comment: Its in pom xml file as a dependency.

Comment: @gishara without more info it's really hard to tell where the error is. maybe you should update yor question and add some details or even post a new question

Comment: I fixed the error by manually correcting the jsoup version in local .m2 repository. Now I can compile your code, but I still could not connect to the URL. Do you have any thoughts on this? I am getting an exception: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out. thanks.

Comment: @gishara you can try to increase the timeout (*Jsoup*  default is 3 secs) - I've updated my answer accordingly

Comment: Thanks for the reply @nyname00. I added the time out, but I am still getting the time out error. :(

Comment: @ nyname00 I set the timeout(0), and now it seems working. Thanks a lot.